# ECS service aws-cli vs. dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Currently experiencing a weird behaviour of AWS ECS tool.

I find 2 different behaviours when using the aws-cli and the web dashboard.

The context is that I have an ECS cluster set up, I am writting a script that automates my deployment by (among other steps) creating or updating an ECS service.

Part of my script uses the command `aws ecs describe-services`
And it is here that I find different information than the dashboard (on the page of my cluster).

Indeed, when the service is created and `ACTIVE` if I run :

```
aws ecs describe-services --services my_service --cluster my_cluster
```

The service will show up as an output with all the informations that I need to parse. It will show up as well on the web dashboard as `ACTIVE`.

The problem is when I delete the service from the dashboard. As expected, it is deleted from the list and I can eventually recreate one from the dashboard with the same name.

But if when the service is deleted,  I re-run the command above, the output will show the service as `INACTIVE` and all the infos about the previously deleted service will still appear.

If the service is deleted, shouldn't the command return the service as `MISSING` :

```
{
    "services": [],
    "failures": [
        {
            "reason": "MISSING",
            "arn": "arn:aws:ecs:<my_regions>:<my_id>:service/my_service"
        }
    ]
}
```

Because this complicates the parsing in my script, and even if I can find a workaround (maybe trying to create the service even if `INACTIVE` rather than not existing), it is kind of weird that even deleted, the service is still here, somewhere, clutering my stack.

Edit : I am using the latest versio of the aws-cli

Comment: What happens if you wait a few minutes?

Comment: The first few minutes after deletion, the cli show the service with a status `DRAINING`, then it becomes `INACTIVE`. After 30min, it is still present and `INACTIVE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behavior provided by aws. Please check below documentation:

> When you delete a service, if there are still running tasks that require cleanup, the service status moves from ACTIVE to DRAINING , and the service is no longer visible in the console or in ListServices API operations. After the tasks have stopped, then the service status moves from DRAINING to INACTIVE . Services in the DRAINING or INACTIVE status can still be viewed with DescribeServices API operations. However, `in the future, INACTIVE services may be cleaned up and purged from Amazon ECS record keeping`, and DescribeServices API operations on those services return a ServiceNotFoundException error.

[delete-service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/delete-service.html)

Comment: Thanks for that, at some point I didnt know where to look for information, and I missed the most obvious article. Hope this clean-up and purge feature will arrive soon, it feels weird having remaining data after I delete something. Hope they also apply this with INACTIVE task definitions too (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=170378)

Comment: true..that will clear the confusion between different  task states and will make our work easier.

Comment: How did you deal with this behaviour? My deployment script is failling because of this :|